# Determining depth in perspective drawing

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

In his Complete Guide to Perspective Drawing (page 27), Craig Attebery proposes a method for determining depth in a line going towards its vanishing point (VP):

[image]

VP = Vanishing Point
HL = Horizon Line
MP = Measuring Point

To put it in words, the author assumes the measuring line will intersect the vanishing point line and the picture plane at the same distance: 2 units. Still, this does not seem to make sense. Here's an apparent proof: the measuring line intersects many lines with different vanishing points. As such lines have different angles, the distance of the interception cannot be all the same:

[image]

Is Attebery (or my interpretation of his work) wrong? If so, how should depth be measured in perspective drawing?

Comment: The first figure is full of things that need more explanation. What is the line parallel to the horizon? What is the significance of the marks $0$, $1$, and $2$ on that line? What is the line from the $2$ mark to VP? What is the "depth" of a line? What else did the author say that you have not told us?

Comment: This may be slightly unrelated, and it's behind a paywall unless there are public options available, but "Where The Camera Was" by Byers and Henle is a good assessment of issues relating to your question and very readable. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.2004.11953261

Comment: Part of the difficulty here is that the author could be correct if the perspective triangle is equilateral (or at least isosceles), but what is listed here is not enough information to determine that triangle's status, unless the author is choosing to measure those distances in that manner, in which case this perspective is defined by that particular choice of distance measurements.

Comment: @DavidK, the line parallel to the horizon is where the line crosses the "picture plane" (drawing window). Marks 0, 1, 2 are measurement units (could be inches, for instance). Perhaps "depth of a line" is indeed inaccurate, more precise wording would be "depth in a line", that is, depth going in one direction.

Comment: @abiessu, I think that might be the way to go. For each Vanishing Point, the author sets a Measuring Point at a given location. More precisely, both the Station Point (eye of the viewer) and the Measuring Point must be at equal distances from the Vanishing Point. How this construction makes measurements valid in the drawing still puzzles me, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what distance is being measured, the distance to the vanishing point from any other point in the figure is infinite.

But the lines through MP are all parallel in the scene, so lines that cut the viewing plane at uniformly spaced points will also cut the line from $0$ to VP at uniformly spaced points.

Any claim that the segment marked "$2$" is the same length as the segment between the marks $0$ and $2$, however, is a claim that those two segments are legs of an isosceles triangle, which is equivalent to a claim about a relationship between the direction to the vanishing point and the direction to the measuring point.
This implies that the choice of measuring point depends on the choice of vanishing point.

Whether this particular technique gives the claimed result or not depends on how the directions to points in the scene map to points on the horizon and on how the technique tells us to decide on the position of the measuring point given the position of the vanishing point.